# firewall pattern with parameters on anonymous asking for login

Tags: silex, symfony-security

I have a route that has a parameter and its tripping my firewall thinking it needs to be logged in first. I tried to setup the pattern to use the name form at as used in the route but it still saying it requires authentication.

is there a special way to get the patter to work with parameters? I'm failing to see how to so that.

Thanks

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
'security.firewalls' => [
    'login' => [
        'pattern' => '^/login$',
        'anonymous' => true
    ],
    'pwdRecovery' => [
        'pattern' => '^/recover',
        'anonymous' => true
    ],
    'newPassword' => [
        'pattern' => '^/newpassword$',
        'anonymous' => true
    ],
    // Any other URL requires auth.
    'authenticated' => [
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'form' => [
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/authenticate'
        ],
        'anonymous' => false,
        'logout'    => ['logout_path' => '/logout'],
        'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
            return new App\Providers\UserServiceProvider();
        }),
    ]
],
'security.access_rules' => [
    ['^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN']
],
'security.encoder.digest' => $app->share(function() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(15);
})
]);
```

Comment: You should post your security configuration in order to get help...

Comment: firewall has been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a regex problem. I can pass parameters to the `^/recover` route just fine.

```
$app->get('/recover/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) use ($app) {
    error_log(print_r((int) $id,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
});
```

But if I add `$` to that route like `^/recover$` then it redirects to login because the dollar sign dictates end of string.

Comment: That solved the problem. I have another problem now but that issue is at least solved, thanks.